# Pointer becomes null c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, function-pointers

I'm new to C++ and this is the code where my pointer becomes null, what am I doing wrong?

Main Function.

```
// in main() function
switch (UserView::RequestMainMenuOption()) {
    case 1:
    {
        struct user_info *user; // the pointer in question.
        if (UserController::Login(user) && user) { // shows null here
            std::cout << user->username << std::endl; // this line does not execute.
```

Controller.

```
bool UserController::Login(struct user_info *user)
{
    //...
    // std::cin username / password and validate in the user model.
    if (User::ValidateCredentials(username, password, user)) {...}
}
```

Model.

```
int User::ValidateCredentials(std::string username, std::string password, struct user_info *user) 
    { 
        // UserList is a vector of struct user_info that contains std::string username, password;
        std::vector<user_info> UserList = User::GetUserList();
        // index is searched for here based on credentials...
        // address of the element in the user list is assigned to user.
        user = &UserList.at(index);
        // address is successfully assigned (tested) 
        // but when returning back to the first function call in the main() function, user is NULL.
```

Comment: You probably want to pass the argument to `Login()` by reference.

Comment: You're passing `user`, everywhere, by value. Which means that setting `user` inside that function has absolutely no effect, whatsoever. You need to pass `user` by reference, instead of value. Review the material in your C++ book that talks about passing function parameters by value versus by reference.

Comment: you are only declaring `struct user_info *user;` and not allocating it, so it's NULL, but you are lucky because if you weren't in debug mode it could contain garbage and execute your code being garbage

Comment: You should also not try take the address of a element in a `std::vector` and then keep using it. (which is what I think you're trying to do, albeit wrongly). A totally unrelated operation on the vector may cause it to move it's contents, invalidating your pointer.

Comment: thanks guys, I was able to solve this issue by malloc-ing the struct in the declaration + using memcpy instead of a direct assignment in the model.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer may not or may not be be null, but more importantly it's uninitialised:

```
struct user_info *user /* = ???? initialise here */; // the pointer in question.
if (UserController::Login(user) && user) { // shows null here
     std::cout << user->username << std::endl; // this line does not execute.
```

EDITED the below to make it **safe for work** thanks to Quentin

It's because your compiler in debug mode is setting it to null..  You want:

```
 std::unique_ptr<user_info> user = std::make_unique<user_info)>(/* constructor arguments go here */);
```

or if the object is shared:

```
 std::shared_ptr<user_info> user = std::make_shared<user_info)>(/* constructor arguments go here */);
```

Comment: Argh, raw owning pointers...